# How do I make my male character take off his bra?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

My Baldur's Gate 3 character was created as a male Dragonborn with body type 1. After starting the game and switching to camp clothes, I discovered that my character was wearing a bra. I tried switching underwear with male party members Will and Astarion, but a bra somehow appears when my character equips their undergarments. The bra goes away if I unequip my underwear, but I'd prefer not to go commando for the entire adventure.

How do I get my male character to stop wearing a bra?

[image: Inventory screen of a dragonborn wearing a bra]

Comment: Out of context, this will be a hot question, by all means.

Comment: This is a very interesting... problem.

Comment: It suits him, what's the problem?

Comment: @pinckerman Maybe more suitable for interpersonal skills SE? ;-)

Comment: @pinckerman - I only came over to make a joke about at least buying him dinner first.

Comment: The question title by itself is already golden. The screenshot literally made me **LOL** And this being a legit serious question makes it even better. Oh dear... my eyes just skimmed the part about *“The bra goes away if I unequip my underwear”*  Please, stop... SE isn't ready...

Answer (score 23):

The short answer is... you *aren't* playing a male dragonborn -- at least, as far as your clothes are concerned!

An adventurer's raiment does not consider voice, pronouns, or anything other than which "body type" is selected at character creation. And Baldur's Gate 3 has a finite selection in that respect.

[image]

[image]

This is much clearer for elves, but the crux of it is: picking 1 or 3 defaults to a "Female" identity and a "Feminine" voice (the even numbered voices), and picking 2 or 4 defaults to a "Male" identity and a "Masculine" voice (the odd numbered voices)

Likewise, picking body type 1 on a dragonborn...
[image]

Defaults to female identity and voice.

**And so the short of it is, clothing ignores the "identity" selected by the player.**

This is almost assuredly a technical limitation -- the fact that there's no way to deform the body skeleton at all implies each piece of clothing has  specific render models (one per type) rather than a single model that is transformed to fit the given skeleton.

So if you want to be a dragonborn with the smaller build? You're stuck with the bra.

Comment: A functional solution, that I leave as an exercise to the reader, is to find a mod that removes the "top" part from the underwear model, since it seems entirely plausible that such mods exist.

Comment: While such a mod might exist, the anatomy that becomes visible without the bra might not be very much suggesting a male character.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Not with dragonborn! There's nothing "underneath" the bra on either type of dragonborn. Just more scales. Interestingly, some kinds of clothing seem to actually add a bigger chest than what they actually have - I'm guessing it's just using a generic female model for it instead of considering the race.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: The question reports that there's an in-game option to remove undergarments entirely, but it lacks the granularity to just go topless and they prefer not to go commando.  So yes, the game is already able to render nude female dragonborn.

Comment: So the UI doesn't indicate what "equipment" each body type has? That's annoying. And would be fixable with a mod so that you don't have to look it up online.

Comment: @SkySpiral7: The UI does not indicate genitalia, because there is a separate option to choose genitalia independently of the body type (not shown in these screenshots). For races other than Dragonborn, it is (presumably) obvious whether or not the body type includes breasts or other "feminine" traits such as waist-hip ratio etc, because you can just look at the model.

Comment: @Kevin ah so it's just the Dragonborn breasts that are unlabeled. That's a smaller gap.

Comment: @SkySpiral7 I think the issue might even just be that dragonborns, regardless of body type, apparently don't have breasts and therefore probably none of them need bras. They're not exactly mammals, so this is a nice touch imo, but clearly this worldbuilding exception got lost somewhere on the way to the undergarment code.

Comment: @KernelPanic: Possibly, they're just reusing the models from the more humanoid races, but with breast size forced to minimum (or even lower than minimum). Most game engines do support *some* mesh deformation to fit the actual shape of the body, it's just typically not very flexible. Still, I can't imagine it would be all that much work to define a separate underwear mesh that only includes the lower half.

Comment: @KernelPanic Fun trivia: in 4e (where the Dragonborn as we know them originated), they very much did; they both hatched from eggs, then nurse their young until their teeth come in. (cite: Ecology of the Dragonborn, Dragon #365, page 28)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Maybe they have teats without permanent breast tissue. A lot of other parts of their anatomy isn't very reptilian so who knows.